# Provision S3 bucket that support CMS-KMS encryption - Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Provision S3 bucket that support CMS-KMS encryption

I created the s3 module that support encryption but I got an error .

I want both the encryption value if some want to put the KMS he will do and it no CMS-KMS key is wenter by user then the default will be create AES256

This is my main.tf code

```
    // s3 bucket

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "delivery" {
  #bucket = "sample-bucket-test-udl"
  bucket        = "${var.udl-tenant}-${var.udl-core}-delivery"
  force_destroy = true
}

// server_side_encryption 

resource "aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" "delivery" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.delivery.id

  rule {
    apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
       kms_master_key_id = try(server_side_encryption_kms_key, null)
  sse_algorithm     = can(server_side_encryption_kms_key) ? "aws:kms" : "AES256"
    }
  }
}

// bucket_versioning  

resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "delivery" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.delivery.id
  versioning_configuration {
    status = "Disabled"
  }
}


// bucket_public_access_block

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "delivery" {
  bucket                  = aws_s3_bucket.delivery.id
  block_public_acls       = true
  block_public_policy     = true
  ignore_public_acls      = true
  restrict_public_buckets = true
}

// object_ownership

resource "aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls" "delivery" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.delivery.id
  rule {
    object_ownership = "BucketOwnerPreferred"
  }
}

// S3 bucket logging 

resource "aws_s3_bucket_logging" "delivery" {
  bucket        = aws_s3_bucket.delivery.id
  target_bucket = "${var.udl-tenant}-${var.udl-core}-s3-accesslogging"
  target_prefix = aws_s3_bucket.delivery.id
}
```

--------------------Error--------------------------------

```
Error: Invalid reference
│ 
│   on main.tf line 16, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" "delivery":
│   16:        kms_master_key_id = try(server_side_encryption_kms_key, null)
│ 
│ A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid reference
│ 
│   on main.tf line 17, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" "delivery":
│   17:        sse_algorithm     = can(server_side_encryption_kms_key) ? "aws:kms" : "AES256"
│ 
│ A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2Sb8.png)

Comment: Please add the error to the question as well.

Comment: I attached the error that I got could you please help me

Comment: Ok, what is the idea behind using the bucket name in the `can` and `try` functions?

Comment: As recommended, I would need to specify that as the default instead of no KMS key encryption for the cipher algorithm. then update the block's behavior according to the altered default. Since this no longer requires the dynamic optional block design pattern because there are default argument values, the config could be updated where the local is now:

Comment: What is this value `server_side_encryption_kms_key` supposed to represent?

Comment: Did you mean variable.tf

Comment: No, I meant what I have written. What is `server_side_encryption_kms_key` and where is it coming from? If it is in the variables, then please add variables file and any relevant code to the question.

Comment: Do you know how to fix 
A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.